# How do I return more than 200 entities at a time from Horizon?

Tags: horizon

I am running my own stellar node and horizon instance. When I try to get over 200 entities at once I get the error

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:8000/transactions?cursor=&limit=201"
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/bad_request",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The request you sent was invalid in some way.",
  "extras": {
    "invalid_field": "limit",
    "reason": "limit 201 is greater than limit max of 200"
  }
}
```

Is there any way of increasing this limit?

Comment: Looks like the constant is defined as `MaxPageSize` in `services/horizon/internal/db2/page_query.go`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this number is [hard-coded in Horizon](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/6c4398a31522bfe74ade691964ad948a2f414d01/services/horizon/internal/db2/page_query.go#L18) so can't be changed without recompiling. What's your use case for wanting to change it? If you run your own Horizon instance you can remove rate limiting and make as many requests as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Horizon response contains navigation links. Use them to retrieve next or previous results page.

Serving huge batches form the server is usually discouraged as both a client and server spend to much resources for results serialization/deserialization.